# TypeORM DataSource shows client password error

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have the following data-source.ts file:

```
import {DataSource} from "typeorm";
import path from "path";
import {User} from "./entity/User";
import { config } from "dotenv";

config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    logging: true,
    entities: [
        User,
    ],
    migrations: [
        path.join(__dirname, "./migration/*"),
    ],
});
```

When I try to generate a migration with
`yarn typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./dist/data-source.js migration:generate ./src/migration/init`
the following error occurs:
`SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string`

Any suggestions?

Tried different typeorm configs with no success

Answer (score 1):

It was a database setup error, the code above is 100% correct.

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Global, Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: "mssql",
        host: configService.get<string>("DATABASE_HOST"),
        port: +configService.get<number>("DATABASE_PORT"),
        username: configService.get<string>("DATABASE_USER"),
        password: configService.get<string>("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        database: configService.get<string>("DATABASE_DB"),
        schema: configService.get<string>("DATABASE_SCHEMA"),
        requestTimeout: 6000,
        extra: {
          trustServerCertificate: true,
        },
        options: {
          encrypt: false,
        },
        synchronize: true,
        logging: true,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        entities: [
          UserEntity,
          AddressEntity,
          DivisionEntity,
        ],
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
  ],
})
export class TypeormConfigModule {}
```

This may help ...

Comment: filename would be data-source.module.ts

Comment: And you don't need extra, options for postgresql